# @Modifying annotation flushes the persistence context even without property "flushautomatically=true"

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, annotations, jpql

I am using Spring Data JPA, and I have an entity, `User`:

```
public class User {
    private Integer userId;
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

I defined one query in `UserRepository`:

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete User u where u.isActive=0")
public void deleteInActiveUsers();
```

I am calling above query from service layer as follows:

```
User user = userRepository.findByUserId(1);
user.setActive(false);
userRepository.deleteInActiveUsers();
```

There is a user with userId:1 and isActive: true in the database.
The above code deletes all the users which are inactive along with the user whose id is 1.

What I understand is if I use @Modifying annotation without flushAutomatically=true then it should not delete the user with Id 1, i.e. should not flush the persistence context.

Please let me know what I am missing here. Whether there is a problem in my understanding or there is any other configuration due to which this is happening.

Comment: `Setting the FlushMode on a query controls whether or not the persistence context should be flushed before query execution. `                                                                   In my example I have used @Modifying annotation with **flushautomatically=false**  , which tells that at the time of execution of deleteInActiveUsers(), the current persistence context should not be flushed. so why It is getting flushed and deleting the user with id 1.

Comment: Because `FlushMode` is only a [hint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html), and Hibernate chooses to flush before every modifying query

Comment: @crizzis Now I understand. Thank you for your guidance.